# pandas regex look ahead and behind from a 1st occurrence of character

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, dataframe

I have python strings like below

```
"1234_4534_41247612_2462184_2131_GHI.xlsx"
"1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2462184_2131_PQRST.GHI.xlsx"
"12JSAF34_45aAF34__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2f462184_2131_JKLMN.OPQ.xlsx"
"1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_2131_WXY.TUV.xlsx"
```

I would like to do the below

a) extract characters that appear before and after 1st dot

b) The keywords that I want are always found after the last `_` symbol

For ex: If you look at 2nd input string, I would like to get only `PQRST.GHI` as output. It is after last `_` and before 1st `.` and we also get keyword after 1st `.`

So, I tried the below

```py
for s in strings:
   after_part = (s.split('.')[1])
   before_part = (s.split('.')[0])
   before_part = qnd_part.split('_')[-1]
   expected_keyword = before_part + "." + after_part
   print(expected_keyword)
```

Though this works, this is definitely not nice and elegant way to write a regex.

Is there any other better way to write this?

I expect my output to be like as below. As you can see that we get keywords before and after 1st `dot` character

```
GHI
PQRST.GHI
JKLMN.OPQ
WXY.TUV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lB6c2L/1)):

```py
import re

strings = [
    "1234_4534_41247612_2462184_2131_ABCDEF.GHI.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2462184_2131_PQRST.GHI.xlsx",
    "12JSAF34_45aAF34__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2f462184_2131_JKLMN.OPQ.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_2131_WXY.TUV.xlsx",
]

pat = re.compile(r"[^.]+_([^.]+\.[^.]+)")

for s in strings:
    print(pat.search(s).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
ABCDEF.GHI
PQRST.GHI
JKLMN.OPQ
WXY.TUV
```

Comment: great. can you also explain your regex logic if you don't mind?

Comment: @TheGreat With `[^.]+_([^.]+\.[^.]+)` first I match every non-dot character until `_`, then I'll match (every non-dot character).(every non-dot character) and capture it as a first group. I've put regex101 link to the answer.

Comment: there is one problem though. an exeption in which the above regex doesn't work. For ex: If you look at my modified 1st string in the post now, it should return only `GHI` and not `GHI.xlsx`. It should exclude .xlsx from returning

Answer (score 2):

You can do (try the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/Y1fwKC/1) )

```
df['text'].str.extract('_([^._]+\.[^.]+)',expand=False)
```

Output:

```
0    ABCDEF.GHI
1     PQRST.GHI
2     JKLMN.OPQ
3       WXY.TUV
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: great. can you also explain your regex logic if you don't mind?

Comment: @TheGreat the link to regex101 has a pretty clear explanation on the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with `rsplit()`. Specify `maxsplit`, so that you don't split more than you need to (for efficiency):

```py
[s.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[1].rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0] for s in strings]
# ['GHI', 'PQRST.GHI', 'JKLMN.OPQ', 'WXY.TUV']
```

If there are strings with less than 2 dots and each returned string should have one dot in it, then add a ternary operator that splits (or not) depending on the number of dots in the string.

```py
[x.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0] if x.count('.') > 1 else x 
 for s in strings
 for x in [s.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[1]]]

# ['GHI.xlsx', 'PQRST.GHI', 'JKLMN.OPQ', 'WXY.TUV']
```