# pandas extract keywords after a list of select keywords

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, dataframe

I have a list of strings like below

```
strings = [
    "1234_4534_41247612_2462184_ASN_ABCDEF_GHI_.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2462184_KOR_PQRST_GHI.xlsx",
    "12JSAF34_45aAF34__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2f462184_TWN_JKLMN_abcd_OPQ.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_IND_WXY.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_IND_WXY_TUV.xlsx",
]
```

I would like to do the below

a) Identify `ASN, KOR, IND, TWN` keyword and pick whatever comes after it

b) Identify `.xlsx` keyword and pick whatever comes before it.

c) The resulting output should not start with `_` but it can have underscore in between the keywords of output string (but it should not start with `_`)

I tried the below (Based on inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73896757/pandas-regex-look-ahead-and-behind-from-a-1st-occurrence-of-character/73896828?noredirect=1#comment130481148_73896828)

```
regex_output = re.compile(r"\_[ASN|KOR|TWN|IND]{3}\_([a-zA-Z\_]+)")

for s in strings:
    print(regex_output.search(s).group(1))
```

How can I put a condition that it should be only looking for words before `.xlsx`

I expect my output to be like as shown below (exclude .xlsx keyword and _ symbol before the start of output string)

```
ABCDEF_GHI
PQRST_GHI
JKLMN_abcd_OPQ
WXY
WXY_TUV
```

Comment: do you have a Series or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat your character class 1 or more times in a non greedy way, and then match an optional underscore before matching `.xslx`

```
(?:ASN|KOR|IND|TWN)_([a-zA-Z_]+?)_?\.xlsx
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:ASN|KOR|IND|TWN)` Match any of the alternatives in a non capture group
- `_([a-zA-Z_]+?)` Match an underscore, and capture in **group 1** 1 or more times any of the listed characters, as few as possible using `+?`
- `_?` Match an optional underscore
- `\.xlsx` Match `.xslx

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I3sWaD/1).

```
import re

strings = [
    "1234_4534_41247612_2462184_ASN_ABCDEF_GHI_.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2462184_KOR_PQRST_GHI.xlsx",
    "12JSAF34_45aAF34__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2f462184_TWN_JKLMN_abcd_OPQ.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_IND_WXY.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_IND_WXY_TUV.xlsx",
]

regex_output = re.compile(r"(?:ASN|KOR|IND|TWN)_([a-zA-Z_]+?)_?\.xlsx")

for s in strings:
    m = regex_output.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
ABCDEF_GHI
PQRST_GHI
JKLMN_abcd_OPQ
WXY
WXY_TUV
```

---

Note that this pattern would allow for double underscores like `__` in the string.

If you don't want to allow that, you may use a pattern repeating a single underscore after matching 1 or more chars A-Za-z

```
(?:ASN|KOR|IND|TWN)_((?:[a-zA-Z]+_)*[a-zA-Z]+_?)\.xlsx
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pwmcd0/1).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a DataFrame/Series, you can use `str.extract` with the regex `_(?:ASN|KOR|TWN|IND)_([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z])`:

```
regex = r"_(?:ASN|KOR|TWN|IND)_([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z])"
df['out'] = df['col'].str.extract(regex)
```

output:

```
                                                 col             out
0     1234_4534_41247612_2462184_ASN_ABCDEF_GHI.xlsx      ABCDEF_GHI
1  1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2462184...       PQRST_GHI
2  12JSAF34_45aAF34__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_...  JKLMN_abcd_OPQ
3  1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_24621...             WXY
4  1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_24621...         WXY_TUV
```

Regex:

```
_                      # underscore
(?:ASN|KOR|TWN|IND)    # any of the words
_                      # underscore
([a-zA-Z_]+)           # capture letters/underscore
```

Comment: nice. how can we explictly mention that it should pick words before `.xlsx` keyword

Comment: Here you don't need to, but you could add `\.xlsx` at the end of the regex

Comment: though you have got `()` for both the groups, how does it print or extract only the 2nd group?

Comment: The first group is non capturing `(?:...)`

Comment: when I do `re.findall` it captures the 1st group as well

Comment: I tried like below - `re.findall("_(?:ASN|KOR|TWN|IND|CHN|GER|ANZ)_([a-z_A-Z]*)",filename)`

Comment: I slightly changed my input (for 1st string). So, can I check how can we avoid last underscore from the output string?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Also why do you use a pandas tag if you don't use pandas?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result =  [re.split('.xlsx', re.split('ASN|KOR|IND|TWN', i)[-1])[0].replace('_', '', 1) for i in strings]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/X8JEh8/1)):

```py
import re

strings = [
    "1234_4534_41247612_2462184_ASN_ABCDEF_GHI_.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2462184_KOR_PQRST_GHI.xlsx",
    "12JSAF34_45aAF34__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41247612_2f462184_TWN_JKLMN_abcd_OPQ.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_IND_WXY.xlsx",
    "1234_4534__sfhaksj_DHJKhd_hJD_41FA247612_2462184_IND_WXY_TUV.xlsx",
]

pat = re.compile(r"(?:ASN|KOR|IND|TWN)_(.*?)_?\.xlsx")

for s in strings:
    m = pat.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
ABCDEF_GHI
PQRST_GHI
JKLMN_abcd_OPQ
WXY
WXY_TUV
```

Comment: what does this part do? - `(.*?)_?`

Comment: @TheGreat `(.*?)_?` Means get everything 'till `_`, where `_` is optional (`?`)